# Sort the LinkedList of Linkedlist based on it's index value sum

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, linked-list

I wants to sort the LinkedList<LinkedList> in such way that, it should calculated index based sum of each nested linkedlist, and then do the sort based on the sum of those column.
for example in the below list:

```
> [[0, 3, 1], [3, 5, 2], [4, 1, 0]]
> 
> Sum of element at 0th index of nested LinkedList is => 0 + 3 + 4 = 7
> Sum of element at 1st index of nested LinkedList is => 3 + 5 + 1 = 9
> Sum of element at 2nd index of nested LinkedList is => 1 + 2 + 0 = 3
```

so, from above, we gets that our sorting should be 3,7,9

to achieve this, we should get below sorting list here, each nested LinkedList, has shuffled by it's index to get the sorting order.

```
[[1, 0, 3], [2, 3, 5], [0, 4, 1]]

Sum of element at 0th index of nested LinkedList is => 1 + 2 + 0 = 3
Sum of element at 1st index of nested LinkedList is => 0 + 3 + 4 = 7
Sum of element at 2nd index of nested LinkedList is => 3 + 5 + 1 = 9
```

I have added the solution for this sorting order in below code, but I think it's complicated as I do the transpose of List, and then sort it, and then again takes the transpose.

Can you please add the best possible approach to get this sorting?

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<Integer>> a = new LinkedList<>();

        List<Integer> a1 = new LinkedList<>();
        List<Integer> a2 = new LinkedList<>();
        List<Integer> a3 = new LinkedList<>();


        a1.add(0);
        a1.add(3);        
        a1.add(1);

        a2.add(3);
        a2.add(5);        
        a2.add(2);

        a3.add(4);
        a3.add(1);        
        a3.add(0);

        a.add(a1);
        a.add(a2);
        a.add(a3);

        System.out.println(a);
        
        a = transpose(a);
        Collections.sort(a, new Comparator<List<Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(List<Integer> sList1, List<Integer> sList2) {
                return sList1.stream().reduce(0, Integer::sum).compareTo(sList2.stream().reduce(0, Integer::sum));               
            }
        });
        a = transpose(a);
        System.out.println(a);
    }
    static List<List<Integer>> transpose(List<List<Integer>> a) {
        List<List<Integer>> ret = new LinkedList<>();
        final int N = a.get(0).size();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            List<Integer> col = new LinkedList<>();
            for (List<Integer> row : a) {
                col.add(row.get(i));
            }
            ret.add(col);
        }
        return ret;
    }

       
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my approach.

(**Note:** This solution builds a new sorted list and doesn't mutate the input. See **UPDATE** to sort the input list).

First, I would have a private class (or a Record in Java 14+) for representing the `column` and `sum` combination.

Next, I would build `List<ColumnToSum>` to capture the sum for each column in the nested list. Then sort it based on the sum (if two columns have the same sum, sort by column index). Get the column indexes sorted by sum.

Once we this, we would have the ordering requirement i.e., we would have the index/column order by which we want to sort each list element in the nested list (`2, 1, 0` in your example).

With this, finally, we can build the sorted list by just arranging the integers as per the ordering requirement we have established.

```
private static class ColumnToSum {
    int col;
    int sum;

    ColumnToSum(int col, int sum) {
        this.col = col;
        this.sum = sum;
    }

    public int getCol() {
        return col;
    }

    public int getSum() {
        return sum;
    }
}

List<ColumnToSum> columnToSums = new ArrayList<>();
for (int j = 0; j < a.get(0).size(); j++) {
    int colSum = 0;
    for (List<Integer> nestedList : a) {
        colSum += nestedList.get(j);
    }
    columnToSums.add(new ColumnToSum(j, colSum));
}

columnToSums.sort(Comparator.comparing(ColumnToSum::getSum)
        .thenComparingInt(ColumnToSum::getCol));

// collect the indexes in order
List<Integer> indexOrdering = columnToSums.stream()
        .map(ColumnToSum::getCol)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<List<Integer>> sorted = new LinkedList<>();

// Construct new list as per the indexOrdering
for (List<Integer> nestedList : a) {
    List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int index : indexOrdering) {
        list.add(nestedList.get(index));
    }
    sorted.add(list);
}
System.out.println(sorted); //[[1, 0, 3], [2, 3, 5], [0, 4, 1]]
```

---

**UPDATE:**

The last step can be done in a different way so that we sort the input list itself.

Once we have built the `indexOrdering`, we can sort each nested list by comparing the index of the element to the `indexOrdering` and determine the final ordering.

```
a.forEach(n -> n.sort((e1, e2) -> Integer.compare(
        indexOrdering.indexOf(n.indexOf(e1)),
        indexOrdering.indexOf(n.indexOf(e2)))
));
```

We can simplify this using [Comparator.comparingInt](https://javadevcentral.com/java-comparator-comparing) as

```
a.forEach(n -> n.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(
            e -> indexOrdering.indexOf(n.indexOf(e)))));
```

Note that `indexOf` is `O(n)` operation.